# Files not being uploaded in the specified path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to upload a `.png` file using below source code. These codes are executed successfully without having any error and Directory also created as per the mentioned path. But file is not being uploaded on that path.

```
public bool SaveFile(string Filepath, string FileContainer, string FileNewName)
{
    IMMAuthenticationManager iMMAuthenticationManager = null;
    IConfiguration iConfig = null;
    FileUtility FU = new FileUtility(iMMAuthenticationManager, iConfig);
    var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[FileContainer];
    bool FileData = FU.FileUtilityUpload2(Filepath, file, FileNewName);
    return FileData;
}
public bool FileUtilityUpload2(string path, IFormFile file, string FileNewName)
{               
    if (file != null)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        if (file.FileName != "")
        {
            var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            //uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;
            string fileSavePath = Path.Combine(path, FileNewName);
            MemoryStream streamfileSavePath = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileSavePath));
            file.CopyToAsync(streamfileSavePath);
            return true;
        }          
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here value of `fileSavePath` is `C:\\Development\MedicalMonitor\Task\DEMO1001\Task1666027260354.png`.

Is there any mistake in the above code?

Comment: Could you please show code that saves the file to the path? There is none in what is currently shown in the post.

Comment: can you provide the code for saving file. Does this `.CopyToAsync()` alone work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `MemoryStream` upload file, You can use this code:

```
public bool FileUtilityUpload2(string path, IFormFile file, string FileNewName)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                if (file.FileName != "")
                {
                    //var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                    //uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;
                    
                    using (MemoryStream streamfileSavePath = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        string fileSavePath = Path.Combine(path, FileNewName);
                        using (var fs = new FileStream(fileSavePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                             streamfileSavePath.WriteTo(streamfileSavePath);
                        }
                    }
                        
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Or, You can also use the asynchronous method recommended by the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0), it is simpler

```
public async Task<bool> FileUtilityUpload2(string path, IFormFile file, string FileNewName)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                if (file.FileName != "")
                {
                    var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                    //uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;
                    string fileSavePath = Path.Combine(path, FileNewName);

                    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(fileSavePath))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        
                    }
                    return true;                        
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Then in `SaveFile`:

```
public bool SaveFile(string Filepath, string FileContainer, string FileNewName)
{
    //............
    bool FileData = FileUtilityUpload2(Filepath, file, FileNewName).IsCompleted;
    return FileData;
}
```